# Removing "\n" from columns name in Pandas dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file having column names with line breaks when I read the file with
`pd.read_csv()`
it returns the column names like this *Violent\ncrime\nrate*. how do I replace *\n* with  *"_"*  for all these columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
df.columns = [c.replace("\n", "_") for c in df.columns]
print(df)
```